# Insert DateTime.now() Lightswitch HTML

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to write the current date/time to a field in SQL, data type is DateTime, in Lightswitch HTML.

Basically, when a user saves any edit to a particular screen, I would like for the date and time to be recorded and show on the screen.

In LS, I have a property called DtLastChangedBy. It is the DateTime column in SQL.

I am selecting the AddEditScreen and choosing Write Code > before_applyChanges to modfiy the method.

So far, I have tried things like this...

```
myapp.AddEditDevice.beforeApplyChanges = function (screen) {
  // Write code here.
  screen.AddEditDevice.DtLastChangeBy
  return Date.now();
};
```

But I think my js is very lacking =(.

Any suggestions? I will eventually like to return the logged in user as well, so it will show X user last saved this record at X time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant approach would be to use the server side 'entity_Created' and 'entities_Updating' methods.

This ensures that the fields are updated for both client and server generated updates.  It also easily accommodates updating a user field (as proposed at the end of your post).

To implement this approach you'll need to select the 'Write Code' button on your Device table's designer screen and select both of the corresponding 'General Methods' options.

This will allow you to introduce the following c# code into the 'entity_Created' general method:

```
partial void Device_Created()
{
    this.DtLastChangeBy = DateTime.Now;
    this.UserLastChangeBy = this.Application.User.Name;
}
```

And the following into the 'entity_Updating' general method:

```
partial void Devices_Updating(Device entity)
{
    entity.DtLastChangeBy = DateTime.Now;
    entity.UserLastChangeBy = this.Application.User.Name;
}
```

In the above snippets I've used the field name 'UserLastChangeBy' to mirror the name you've used for your DateTime field.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much. I take it the Application.User.Name will retrieve a logged in user once I have users set up for Forms Authentication. Right now, in debug, it returns TestUser. I do not have any users setup at the moment. Also, I noticed that the time is correct when the screen is created, but is wrong when apply changes. I have to reload the whole page for the time to show correct again.

Comment: Your expectation is spot on regarding the username.  On the date front, in what way is it incorrect when you apply changes?  For example, is it shown as blank or is it an hour out?

Comment: When I apply changes on the screen, the page navigates back to the browse screen. If I go straight back into the same item I just edited, the time is way off. I just did this at 7:29am on the 10th and the time stamp is 1:29:14am on the 10th. Thank you!

Comment: If you do a F5 refresh before going into the item does it then show the correct value?

Comment: Yes, F5 on the browse screen and then selecting the item, the correct time does show.

Comment: One more question. Sorry. If I get Windows Authentication going with access managed by an AD Security Group - will LS pull that user the way it is pulling from the integrated Users table now? Or will that be a different setup? Thank you!

Comment: On the date issue, which country are you based in?  As regards the AD security it should pull through in the same fashion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103122/discussion-between-creedc-and-chris-cook).

Answer (score 0):

I am using an 'answer' just so I can post code. I used this to manage the Browse Screen refresh...

```
myapp.BrowseDevices.Devices_ItemTap_execute = function (screen) {
// Write code here.
myapp.showAddEditDevice(screen.Devices.selectedItem, {
    //beforeShown: function (addEditOrderLines) {
    //addEditOrderLines.OrderLines = screen.OrderLines.selectedItem;
    //},
    afterClosed: function (addEditDevice, navigationAction) {
        if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
            screen.Devices.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

};

If there is a more smooth/elegant way to do this, I would love to know! I am sure the date issue can be fixed somewhere else(?).

Thank you!

Comment: It may be more appropriate to post this as a separate question which should give it more visibility.

Comment: I think you can work around that by setting the value of the contentItem on the screen via javascript before you submit it to the server. That should give your client side item the "correct" value, and the answer Chris gave will overwrite the value when it hits the server. The difference will be negligible, and the next time you run a query that retrieves the data from the server, the server side value will get displayed. If you need details just post another question.